# Cannot process argument transformation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13976999/107537), I created the script below `DOSCommands.ps1`

```
Function Invoke-DOSCommands {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$cmd,
        [String]$tmpname = $(([string](Get-Random -Minimum 10000 -Maximum 99999999)) + ".cmd"),
        [switch]$tmpdir = $true)
    if ($tmpdir) {
        $cmdpath = $(Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath $tmpname);
    }
    else {
        $cmdpath = ".\" + $tmpname
    }
    Write-Debug "tmpfile: " + $cmdpath
    Write-Debug "cmd: " + $cmd
    echo $cmd | Out-File -FilePath $cmdpath -Encoding ascii;
    & cmd.exe /c $cmdpath | Out-Null
}

Invoke-DOSCommands "Echo ""Hello World""", -tmpdir $false
```

However, on execution it returns this error:

```
Invoke-DOSCommands : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'cmd'. Cannot convert value to type S ystem.String.
At DOSCommands.ps1:20 char:19
+ Invoke-DOSCommands <<<<  "Echo ""Hello World""", -tmpdir $false
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-DOSCommands], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Invoke-DOSCommands
```

I've searched for this error but can't figure it out. It seems to me that it can't convert the string type correctly! Please help!

Comment: You have a comma after the string you want to pass as parameter `$Cmd`.

Comment: if you are using PS V3, you can use the escape sting `--%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `--%` in PowerShell V3 or higher.  See this [blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/) I wrote on using `--%`.  In V1/V2 the situation is just bad as you can see in this [Connect bug on the issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible#tabs).  The common workaround in V1/V2 is to use Start-Process or .NET's Process.Start.  From those list of workarounds, I kind of like this one:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("Cmd", "/c anything you want to put here with embedded quotes, and variables")
```

Which is effectively what `--%` does to the parsing of all parameters following it i.e. it parses them in a dumbed down mode similar to cmd.exe parameter parsing including expanding env vars referenced with `%envVarName%`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. However, when launching the cmd.exe, how do we use the comspec variable and ensure the same working directory as the current powershell script?

Comment: @Vijay If you use the Start overload that takes a `StartProcessInfo` object, you can set the `WorkingDirectory` in that StartProcessInfo object.

Comment: Documentation [Process.start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Process.StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'm guessing this is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, there is a WorkingDirectory property on StartInfo. You create an instance of that and pass it as a parameter to Process.Start().

Answer (score 2):

Alright based on the answer by Keith I've modified my function as follows:

```
Function Invoke-DOSCommands {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$cmd)

    $comspec =  $env:comspec # have to get comspec
    $cwd = Get-Location # ensure correct working directory
    $pstartinfo = new-object -type System.Diagnostics.processStartInfo -Argumentlist "$comspec","/c $cmd"
    $pstartinfo.WorkingDirectory= $cwd
    Write-Debug "cmd: $pstartinfo.FileName"
    Write-Debug "args: $pstartinfo.Arguments"
    Write-Debug "dir: $pstartinfo.WorkingDirectory"
    #[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("Cmd", "/c $cmd")
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pstartinfo)
}

Invoke-DOSCommands "Echo ""Hello World"" & dir & pause" # testing function
```